# WPF Modal dialog dataBindings

Tags: wpf, data-binding, modal-dialog

I have a PropertyGrid which is used in a side panel of my application, and the databindings for this PropertyGrid are setup in XAML.  I would like to use this same PropertyGrid in a Modal dialog box, but when I do all changes made in the dialog box immediately affect the underlying properties.   Is there an easy way to prevent the databindings from affecting the source properties until an accept button is pressed?  Or is there some other way to accomplish this?  I am trying to not duplicate the XAML for the PropertyGrid which is what using UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit would require.

Comment: You could have the UpdateSourceTrigger passed as a parameter to a User Control. No need to duplicate here...

Answer (score 0):

You can set `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` on the bindings in question, so they won't propagate immediately. Then, when you press the accept button, wire it up to a command which calls `textBox1.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.Text).UpdateSource()` or similar for each piece of data you want to send back to the ViewModel.